# Find a point that the distance from 2 or more points is the same

Tags: geometry

I'm going to find a point x where the distance from point a to x is the same from point b to x.

[Here is the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxKS5.png)

If a is (0,0) and b is (10,0), then x is (5,0).

I want to find x for other a and b.

Also is it possible to find the point x for 3 or more points?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangulation

Comment: There are an infinite number of solutions for two points, lying on the line that crosses the line joining the two points at its midpoint at a right angle. For three points, unless they line on a straight line, there will be a circle for which all three lie n the circumference (and so are equidistant from the centre).

Comment: Just to comment on Joffan's comment, for three non-collinear points there is one unique solution to your problem. For four or more points, there is in general no solution, unless these points are [cocyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concyclic_points), in which case the solution is the center of the circle.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two points $x$ will be anywhere on the perpendicular bisector.

In your case, $x$ has to have $x$ coordinate $5$ and the $y$ coordinate 
could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Given two points $A$ $(x_A, y_A)$ and $B$ $(x_B, y_B)$, the co-ordinates of $x$ are simply $(\frac{x_A+x_B}{2}, \frac{y_A+y_B}{2})$

Comment: How to do this for 3 points?

Comment: With the point $C$ $(x_C, y_C)$, the midpoint simply becomes $(\frac{x_A+x_B+x_C}{3}, \frac{y_A+y_B+y_C}{3})$

Comment: I've tried it [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/e2aat2aqxj), but it's not working